# Powershell script - Transcript - How I disable it

Tags: powershell, group-policy, transcription

I have got powershell script. Over scheduler I run bat file which run PS1 file.

BAT file

```
Powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File script.PS1
```

PS1 file

```
$path = "D:\data";
$limit = (Get-Date).AddHours(-3);
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.CreationTime -lt $limit } | Remove-Item -Force;
```

In the same directory the powershell creates directories in format YYYYMMDD with files PowerShell_transcript.SERVER.t7eh07Gy.20230914031500.txt. Here is the entire script run.

For example:
D:\data\20230914\PowerShell_transcript.SERVER.t7eh07Gy.20230914031500.txt
D:\data\20230915\PowerShell_transcript.SERVER.t7eh07Gy.20230914031500.txt
etc.

How do I disable it?

I have tried stop-transcript, and etc.

I need to stop transcript.

Comment: The start of transcription can be determined by group policy and executed independently of your script. Check the policy for example here: `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription\`

Comment: Here is EnableTranscripting=1

Comment: This indicates that your system administrator has configured automatic transcription of all scripts.

Comment: I have changed it to EnableTranscripting=0. It looks fine.

Comment: Check the setting after reboot, it may be applied by group policies at each login or after certain periods of time. If you don't mind I will add this as an answer.

Comment: After restart is old value back. I have to solve it with admins. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The start of transcription can be determined by group policy and executed independently of your script. Check the policy for example here:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription
```

If there is a **EnableTranscripting** value in this key and it isn't equal to zero, then transcription is enabled.

Comment: Will this work? `Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription -Name EnableTranscripting`? It will return $null if the value does not exist.

Comment: @lit, yes, if you add `-ErrorAction Ignore`. You can also use `Get-ItemPropertyValue` to return the value (data) only. Given that transcribing may also be enabled with a _user_ (HKCU) GPO, you must check _two_ locations (if defined in _both_, the HKLM policy takes precedence): Therefore, check `Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Ignore -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription -Name EnableTranscripting` first, then `Get-ItemPropertyValue -ErrorAction Ignore -Path HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription -Name EnableTranscripting`

Answer (score 1):

[Re1ter's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77112776/45375) has provided the crucial pointer; let me add some **background information**:

- What you're seeing are the effects of an enabled `Turn on PowerShell Transcription` GPO (group-policy [object]), which results in *automatic transcriptions* of all PowerShell sessions (whether interactive or not), as if you had called [`Start-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript) and [`Stop-Transcript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/stop-transcript) at the start and end of each session).
- If this policy is enabled:

  - The transcripts are stored inside calendar-day-specific directories using the name format `yyyMMdd`, e.g. `20230918` on 18 Sept. 2023, in files using the name format `PowerShell_transcript.*.*.*.txt`, where the `*` components represent the following, in order:

    - the computer name (e.g. `server1`)
    - a random string of 8 alphanumeric characters (e.g. `IjrFVsl1`)
    - a sortable local timestamp; the equivalent of `[datetime]::Now.ToString('s') -replace '\D'` at the start of the session (e.g, ``)
    - Example:

      - `PowerShell_transcript.server1.IjrFVsl1.20230918162121.txt`
  - The calendar-day-specific directories are stored in the user's `Documents` directory by default (typically, `$HOME\Documents`; determine with `[System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')`), but the location is configurable.
- The policy settings are stored in the registry, where they can be *queried*, but they shouldn't be *modified* there (which you could technically only do as an administrator): registry modifications aren't synced with the originating GPOs and, in domain environments, may even get overwritten on every reboot / logon.

  - Instead, the policies should be managed either via the `gpedit.msc` GUI or the cmdlets in the [`GroupPolicy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy) PowerShell modules.
- The policy can be defined either at the *machine* level, stored in the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` (`HKLM:`) registry hive, or at the *user* level, stored in each user's `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` (`HKCU:`) registry hive.

  - If policies are defined at *both* levels (which doesn't make sense), the machine-level policy takes precedence.
- [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) has *separate* policies from *Windows PowerShell*, although it can be configured to delegate to the latter's policies.

---

The following **`Get-AutomaticTranscriptionSettings` convenience function** (source code in the bottom section) queries the registry directly in order to **report the effective policy settings** and therefore doesn't require the `GroupPolicy` module, which would require installation of the RSAT tools.

Sample call:

```bash
PS> Get-AutomaticTranscriptionSettings

Enabled                     : True
OutputPathPattern           : C:\Users\jdoe\Documents\2*\PowerShell_transcript.*.*.*.txt
IncludeInvocationHeaders    : False
PSEdition                   : Core
UsesWindowsPowerShellPolicy : True
GPOScope                    : Machine
RegistryKey                 : {HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\Transcription, HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription}
```

The above shows an enabled PowerShell (Core) policy at the machine level that delegates to the Windows PowerShell policy (at the same level)

Note that the `OutputPathPattern` property value can be passed directly to `Get-ChildItem` to list all existing transcripts.

---

**`Get-AutomaticTranscriptionSettings` source code**:

```bash
function Get-AutomaticTranscriptionSettings {
  <#
.SYNOPSIS
  Reports the current automatic transcription settings for PowerShell, if any.
.DESCRIPTION
  Targets the edition that is running the script by default, but you change
  that with -Edition, which accepts 'Core' or 'Desktop' (Windows PowerShell)

  If transcribing is enabled, the .OutputPathPattern property of the output 
  object can be passed to Get-ChildItem -Path to find all current transcripts.

  Note that transcripts are stored in calendar-day-specific subfolders using the
  "yyyDDmm" format, with the transcripts file names matching pattern
  "PowerShell_transcript.*.*.*.txt"
#>

  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [ValidateSet('Core', 'Desktop')]
    [Alias('PSEdition')]
    [string] $Edition
  )

  if ($env:OS -ne 'Windows_NT') { throw 'This command runs on Window only.' }

  Set-StrictMode -Version 1

  if (-not $Edition) {
    # Default to the running edition.
    $Edition = ('Desktop', 'Core')[$PSVersionTable.PSEdition -eq 'Core']
  }
  # Normalize the casing
  $Edition = [char]::ToUpperInvariant($Edition[0]) + $Edition.Substring(1).ToLowerInvariant()

  $regKeys = [ordered] @{
    Desktop = [ordered] @{
      HKLM = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription'
      HKCU = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\Transcription'
    }
    Core    = [ordered] @{
      HKLM = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\Transcription'
      HKCU = Get-Item -ErrorAction Ignore -LiteralPath 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\PowerShellCore\Transcription'
    }    
  }

  $effectiveValue = $null # The *absence* of the value is the same as 0
  $effectiveKey = $originalKey = $null
  $usesWinPSPolicy = $false
  foreach ($hive in 'HKLM', 'HKCU') {
    if ($null -ne ($key = $regKeys.$Edition.$hive) -and $null -ne ($value = $key.GetValue('EnableTranscripting'))) {
      if ($Edition -eq 'Core' -and 1 -eq $key.GetValue('UseWindowsPowerShellPolicySetting')) {        
        $usesWinPSPolicy = $true
        $originalKey = $key
        # Use the WinPS settings in the *same hive*
        $key = $regKeys.Desktop.$hive
        $value = if ($null -ne $key) { $key.GetValue('EnableTranscripting') }
      }
      $effectiveKey = $key
      $effectiveValue = $value
      break
    }
  }

  # Construct the output object.
  # Note that the `$(...)` enclosure around the `if` statement is needed for WinPS-compatibility.
  [pscustomobject] @{      
    Enabled                     = 1 -eq $effectiveValue # only 1, specifically, is recognized as the enabling number.
    OutputPathPattern           = $(if ($effectiveKey) { 
        $dir = $effectiveKey.GetValue('OutputDirectory')
        if (-not $dir) { $dir = [System.Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments') }
        # Output dirs are calendar-day specific "yyyyMMdd" dirs., inside of which each session
        # is transcribed in a "PowerShell_transcript.*.*.*.txt" file.
        Join-Path $dir 2*\PowerShell_transcript.*.*.*.txt
      })
    IncludeInvocationHeaders    = $(if ($effectiveKey) { 1 -eq $effectiveKey.GetValue('EnableInvocationHeader') })
    PSEdition                   = $Edition
    UsesWindowsPowerShellPolicy = $(if ($null -ne $effectiveValue) { if ($Edition -eq 'Desktop') { $true } else { $usesWinPSPolicy } })
    GPOScope                    = $(if ($effectiveKey) { ('User', 'Machine')[$effectiveKey -like 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\*'] })
    RegistryKey                 = $(if ($usesWinPSPolicy -and $originalKey) { $originalKey.ToString() } if ($effectiveKey) { $effectiveKey.ToString() })
  }

}
```